# WHERE clause if match

Tags: mysql

What is the simplest way to make part of a `WHERE` clause dependent on the result of a `JOIN`? I realize that is an extremely ambiguous and confusing question, so allow me to simply show you what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM cal_form_answers a
INNER JOIN cal_form_elements e
    USING(element_id)
INNER JOIN cal_forms f
    USING(form_id)
LEFT JOIN members m
    USING(member_id)
WHERE f.org_id = ?
    AND m.org_id = ?
    AND e.form_id = ?
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY a.member_id
```

First, note that the question marks are not invalid syntax—I am using Codeigniter, which uses them as bound parameters.

Line 10 (`AND m.org_id = ?`) is dependent on whether or not the `LEFT JOIN` actually finds something. If there is no match in the `members` table, then Line 10 becomes unnecessary. In fact, it becomes a problem. I would like to limit results by Line 10 *unless* there is no match in the members table. In that event, I would simply like to ignore that part of the `WHERE` clause.

I believe this can be achieved using subqueries, though I am admittedly unsure how to work out the syntax. Is there any other way? If yes, how else can this result be achieved? In the event there is no other way, can somebody demonstrate an implementation of a subquery for this situation, and explain how it works?

Thank you!

Comment: So why don't you specify those conditions in the join condition part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a LEFT JOIN does not match a record, then those LEFT JOINed fields are null. Why not just check if that field IS NULL, and when it is not then check it.)

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM cal_form_answers a
INNER JOIN cal_form_elements e
    USING(element_id)
INNER JOIN cal_forms f
    USING(form_id)
LEFT JOIN members m
    USING(member_id)
WHERE f.org_id = ?
    AND (m.org_id = ? OR m.org_id IS NULL)
    AND e.form_id = ?
GROUP BY a.member_id
ORDER BY a.member_id
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. Despite years of website development, I still find myself unable to think clearly in SQL. I knew it was simple! Thanks. :)